# Fuelphp input xss_clean issues

Tags: fuelphp

Fuel 1.7. I'm working with framework first day.

I'm tried to

```
'input_filter'  => array('Security::xss_clean'),
```

in config.php, but it didn't work.

how i can xss_clean all $_POST/$_GET? I can't do this

```
Security::xss_clean(Input::get('foo'));
```

every time.

can i use rule 'xss_clean' in validation like this example?

```
protected static $_rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|trim|valid_email|max_length[32]|xss_clean',
);
```

where i can find full list of validation rules? in docs i didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [validation](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/classes/validation/validation.html) rules, here is the [list](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/classes/validation/validation.html#rules).

About the **Security::xss_clean**, you should be more specific about what issues are you having.

Answer (score 0):

How did you determine it didn't work?

```
'input_filter'  => array('Security::xss_clean'),
```

should work fine.

Having said that, contrary to a lot of other frameworks, FuelPHP's architecture is designed not to alter original input values, but instead make sure all data being output is rendered harmless.

Also, an xss_clean operation is a very expensive operation, so it's a lot better not to do that by standard and on every request, but only if you have input fields that you need to send back as output unescaped (for example a textarea that contains HTML input).